# Move TYPO3 fileadmin

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

My server has multiple file system disks. TYPO3 is installed below `/opt/`, but this is not suitable for file uploads. I need the fileadmin storage at another location. How can I achieve that in TYPO3?

The first idea was to move the `public/fileadmin` directory and to adjust the path in `...['BE']['fileadminDir']` (LocalConfiguration.php). But then all images were missing in the frontend.

So I reverted that and replaced `public/fileadmin` by a symlink instead:

```
ln -s /data/fileadmin/ /opt/mysite/public/fileadmin
```

This works for the frontend. All images are shown. However, in the backend, all directories have a "lock" icon. I cannot upload files anymore.

I already tried to set `['BE']['lockRootPath']` to `/data/` and `/data/fileadmin/` in both cases, but it had no effect.

The third idea was to add another file storage in TYPO3. I didn't try that yet, because there are already lots of uploaded files and I'm not sure how to move them to the other file storage in a quick and safe way. I don't know which references are involved here.

Comment: What is your target of moving fileadmin? I want to understand why you want to move it? Security? Shared file system?

Comment: There is not much disk space. I'm not the maintainer of the disks but the data disk is larger and maybe gets backups. The install disk is probably faster. But I'm just told where to put what files.

Comment: Maybe adding a second TYPO3 file storage is the best option. If someone could explain how to move the content safely in TYPO3 without losing any refs.

Comment: If you want to *move* the content of the storage, you should do the same for the storage: move it, instead of adding the content to a new storage. `fileadmin` is the default-Storage with UID 1. If you want the content anywhere else, configure this storage to your needs. All references are stored as "1:/<path>", and TYPO3 can find the files on the changed storage-location.

Comment: Do you mean my first idea in the question? So `1:/...` will be kept but let "1" point to a a new path (i.e. `/data/fileadmin`). Maybe you can explain, why I didn't work

Comment: Use the variant where you have the "lock" icon and then give the target folder in `/opt/mysite/...` the permissions for the webserver user (www-data?) to read and write.

Comment: I already set permissions with `chown`. However in this case also FACL entries were set. So thanks for the hint, it made me re-check all permissions. I wrongly thought it's some kind of "directory traversal attack" prevention in TYPO3 that prohibited my symlink. Why not add it as answer, so I can accept it?